# Laravel routing failed

Tags: php, laravel

I have to redirect to a particular `Controller` based on `URL`.

My URL is,

```
http://localhost/project/public/category-1?tracker=category
```

If the query string `tracker` is `category`, then it should redirect to `ProductsController@category` route.

I have tried using the below code. But it doesn't work.

```
Route::any('{name}', function () {
    if (Request::get("tracker") == "category")
        Route::get('{name}', 'ProductsController@category');
});
```

But the below code works when not using `Route` inside `if statement`

```
Route::any('{name}', function () {
    if (AppHelper::decryptURL(Request::get("tracker")) == "category")
        return 1;
});
```

The above code displays `1` in webpage, but when using `Route::get('{name}', 'ProductsController@category')` instead `return 1`it reutn blank page.

How to fix it. Is any problem in my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Route::any('{name}', function () {
    $tracker = $request->query('tracker');
    if($tracker === 'category') {
      return (new \App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController())->category();
    }
});
```

Or via dependency injection

```
Route::any('{name}', function (ProductsController $productsCtrl) {
    $tracker = $request->query('tracker');
    if($tracker === 'category') {
      return $productsCtrl->category();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the right example to take advantage of [**middleware**](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) which allows to hooks some functionality before the request reach the controller and the response been sent to the browser.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckTarget
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->tracker <= "category") {
            return redirect('name_of_your_route');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Afther what you must register the new Middleware in Within `App\Http\Kernel` Class like this

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    \\...
    'target' => auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckTarget::class,
]
```

And to use use you'll do like this

```
Route::any('{name}', function () {
    return view('your_view_file_name');
})
->middleware('target');
->name('any_name_you_want');


Route::any('{name}', function () {
    if (Request::get("tracker") == "category") {
        Route::get('{name}', 'ProductsController@category'); // Here you define another route instead of redirect
    }
});
```

In your code there are one problem which is, instead of redirecting the user to the route which you want you are defining another `Route` inside of another route handle which is uncommon, and should be **avoid**. To redirect you should use `redirect` helper which take a URL to which Laravel will redirect